# Pass hidden value with checkbox together

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a form where I have id of product and id of campaign related with one item. I want to display only one checkbox but pass both productID and campaignID.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'filter', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    @foreach ( $row as $id )
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{ $id->$productID }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="campaignID[]" value="{{ $id->$campaignID }}">
        <input type="submit">
    @endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now when I select one checkbox it passes the correct productID but also it passes all campaingIDs as well.
Is it possible to do it like this?

**Edit**

For example:

- Item A - ProductID: 1, CampaignID: 100
- Item B - ProductID: 2, CampaignID: 200
- Item C - ProductID: 3, CampaignID: 300

When I select item A, I get productID 1, but for campaignID I get 100, 200, 300.

Comment: from the code above, all you need is get the values from whatever script your form is submitting to using the name attributes.. or am i missing something?

Comment: When I do `Input::get('products')` and `Input::get('campaignID')` I get correct value for product, but also I get all campaignIDs, not just the one which I selected. The campaignID is related with each item like productID.

Comment: then you may need a little javascript in your code assuming you don't want to deal with arrays on the serverside, create a third input field of type hidden and name it selectedid or whatever. The onchange, you can populate its value with the new selected value

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems to be better to just pass the product id and retrive the campaing from the related product model.

i.e. like this

Blade Template

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'filter', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    @foreach ( $row as $id )
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{ $id->$productID }}">
        <input type="submit">
    @endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller

```
$product_id = ...
$product = Product::find($product_id);
$campaign_id = $product->campaignId;
```

Comment: But in this case I'd need a loop on server side to extract campaignIds? Can it be done on client side since I'm receiving array with combined product and campaign ids. That array is `$row`.

Comment: If you create the relation on the server, you can be sure, that nobody sends you wrong data (i.e. a product campaign combination, which doesn't exists). If you have to validate this on the server, you saved nothing.

Comment: On top of that, you save some traffic and have smaller requests

Comment: Ok. But what about passing the array of product ids. I need to have option for multiple select. How can I do `Product::find($product_id)` then? It would find data only for last one selected...

Comment: I dont understand your problem.. `$product_id` should be an id (not array) and normally an id is unique inside the database - so you wouldn't never get more than return value? If you pass `::find` an array of id's you get an collection of all matching records over which you could iterate

Comment: It is an id, but if choose more ids, than it is an array of ids.